# Refusing to load URL as it exceeds 2097152 characters

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-web3

I try to load index.html file, javascript file and css file in my project flutter with package flutter_webview. I found this error

[WARNING:navigation_controller_impl.cc(285)] Refusing to load URL as it exceeds 2097152 characters.

what i should to do?

i try to load file index.html and load file javascript and file stle.css, i have to change minSDK to 18 but it is no working

my error [WARNING:navigation_controller_impl.cc(285)] Refusing to load URL as it exceeds 2097152 characters.

Comment: why would you want to use URLs that have more than 2097152 characters?

Comment: i try to integrated new package base javascript in flutter